# Can't find com.google.api.client.extensions.android

Tags: android, sdk

I moved my SDK directory from my laptop to a remote hard drive.  Afterward, I noticed Android Studio can't find

com.google.api.client.extensions.android (see below)

[image]

The app compiles fine and runs fines which makes it more perplexing....

Did anyone have the similar experience?  If so, what's the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there was a conflict in the google.android library.

I added force = true to a handful of libraries and the problem was resolved.  Below is a sample of what I did:

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'){
    force = true
}
compile ('com.android.support:design:26.1.0'){
    force = true
}
// For enabling Google app invite
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.4.2')

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
```